# How do I put the complete UserDefaults list into a tableview - Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, userdefaults

I am trying to put the list of UserDefaullts into a UITableView. I just want each key that I have saved to be able to show up in an individual cell. I placed all the individual items in variables so that they can be easily called. Here is one for example:

```
var A = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "A")
```

I want to be able to put these in an array, but not every var is going to necessarily be used.

I'm sorry if this does not make much sense, I am not able to explain this very well. If you would like me to clarify anything please let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let say you set your items into UserDefaults like this:

```
let array = ["one", "two", "three"]
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(array, forKey: "StringArray")
```

Then you retrieve the items as an array as the following:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let array = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "StringArray") ?? [String]()
```

Then use the array as your UITableView datasource.

**To get all values/keys from User Defaults**:

**Values**:

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().values)
```

**Keys**:

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys)
```

Comment: thank you! I was actually setting multiple items, not one array. So I guess my question is more how do I put the whole UserDefaults dictionary into an array that I can use in a tableview? I just want everything in the UserDefaults in a tableview. Sorry for the confusion